# Can I use pseudo elements with checkboxes?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Display that changes in conjunction with the check box I wrote the following code.

But it doesn't work on Firefox or IE 11. It works on Chrome, which one is right for you?

```css
input:before {
  content: 'no';
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
}

input:checked::before {
  content: 'ok';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="cookie">
```

Comment: Be aware it's `::before` not `:before`

Comment: @johannchopin even `:before` is correct since it's the old definition so browsers are supposed to still support it with the new syntax

Comment: @TemaniAfif I didn't know thank you for the info ;) I'll read more next time

Comment: Yes, it is rendered because of legacy support for  `:before` but only `::before` is correct - it is pseudo-element not a pseudo-class.